# Python dice simulator, why it is running without stopping?

Tags: python, simulation, dice

```
import random

print("This is a dice simulator.")

x = "y"

while x == "y":
    number = random.randint(1,6)

    if number == 1:
        print("------------")
        print("|          |")
        print("|     0    |")
        print("|          |")
        print("------------")

    if number == 2:
        print("------------")
        print("|         0|")
        print("|          |")
        print("|0         |")
        print("------------")

    if number == 3:
        print("------------")
        print("|         0|")
        print("|     0    |")
        print("|0         |")
        print("------------")

    if number == 4:
        print("------------")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|          |")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("------------")

    if number == 5:
        print("------------")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|     0    |")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("------------")

    if number == 6:
        print("------------")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("------------")

x = input("Press y to roll again")
```

I can not figure out why my code is looping without an end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `while x == "y"` : your `x` is set to `"y"` at the beginning before the loop, and never changes *during* the loop.

You may want to change your last line to be *inside* the loop, after the `print` statements.

The fix is therefore very simple :

change the last line from :

```
x = input("Press y to roll again")
```

to

```
    x = input("Press y to roll again")
```

Answer (score 1):

`x = input("Press y to roll again")` is asked outside the `while` loop, therefor the code is never reached. Add it to the `while`:

```
import random

print("This is a dice simulator.")

x = "y"

while x == "y":
    number = random.randint(1,6)

    if number == 1:
        print("------------")
        print("|          |")
        print("|     0    |")
        print("|          |")
        print("------------")

    if number == 2:
        print("------------")
        print("|         0|")
        print("|          |")
        print("|0         |")
        print("------------")

    if number == 3:
        print("------------")
        print("|         0|")
        print("|     0    |")
        print("|0         |")
        print("------------")

    if number == 4:
        print("------------")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|          |")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("------------")

    if number == 5:
        print("------------")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|     0    |")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("------------")

    if number == 6:
        print("------------")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("|0        0|")
        print("------------")

    x = input("Press y to roll again")
```

[Test online!](https://repl.it/repls/BurdensomeColdProgramminglanguages)